# IOS custom system interceptor or security system

Tags: ios, hook, access-control, interception, parental-control

Is it possible to create a security tool for IOS that would control and enable/disable some system calls and resources (e.g. application launching requests, Internet access, etc.)?

I'd like to create an app that will act like a parental control.

We can do this in Windows by a few kinds of system drivers, what about IOS?

Comment: For vanilla iOS, definitely not. You could create a jailbreak tweak to do it.

Comment: Jailbreak is unsuitable. I'd like it to be able in AppStore. What about something like Sandwich, can it help me?

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's so pity that we can't create apps of this kind for IOS...

Answer (score 0):

This feature already exists out of the box in iOS. Apple has a technical article on the topic [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4213).

> You can enable Restrictions, also known as parental controls, on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch. Restrictions stop you from using specific features and applications.

If this is not enough, googling around led me to several other applications that achieve parental control. Here's a [summary from Tom's Guide](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/pictures-story/596-best-parental-control-apps.html).